# Magento can't create order in admin due to JS errors

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

In Magento we have just put a new site live and cannot create orders in the backend

After clicking the 'create new order' button you get to the customer list and you cannot select a customer due to JS errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'select' of null configure.js:74
ProductConfigure._initWindowElements configure.js:74
ProductConfigure.initialize configure.js:57
klass prototype.js:101
(anonymous function) configure.js:764
_createResponder.responder

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of null sales.js:1214
OrderFormArea.initialize sales.js:1214
klass prototype.js:101
(anonymous function) sales.js:48
(anonymous function) prototype.js:391
_createResponder.responder
```

The functionality works perfectly on the test site, the only differences between the 2 are caching, which i've tried refreshing etc and hasn't solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was down to an old PHP version in the end

Old server was running PHP 5.2.17

Upgraded to 5.4.15

Discovered this by it being the only thing different between the new and old servers

Comment: Please provide more information before you accept this as the answer. (e.g.: What issue with the old version of PHP was resolved in the new version, how did you discover the problem, etc.)